# Javascript, find object in list of objects by id

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list of objects in where I need to find one specifically by an ID. So very simply like so:

```
{ 
 {
   "id": "1"
 },{
   "id": "2"
 }
}
```

I have a function where I want to find the object by it's id, that does not work like so

```
 function findOb (id) {

   return _.find(myList, function(obj) { return obj.id === id } );

 }
```

it is not returning the correct object (this is using lodash) uncertain what I am doing incorrect and could use some help. Thanks!

*edit* - I don't know if this helps but I am building and trying to search an object in this format - https://github.com/pqx/react-ui-tree/blob/gh-pages/example/tree.js . So there are just objects with module and leaf sometimes, and I want to be able to search and find by the 'module' key. Thanks for the feedback everyone!

Comment: Your object doesn't have keys.

Comment: I am stuck like that right now, is there a way to achieve this without keys?

Comment: can you confirm this is a valid JSON object? it does not look like valid JSON

Comment: @ajmajmajma How about using an array of objects? `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`.

Comment: @Xufox and put the `id`s in double quotes (like `"id"`) so you have valid JSON object?

Comment: @ochi That's needed in JSON, but not in Javascript literals.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough... I misunderstood

Comment: The outer `{ }` should be `[ ]` to make it an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should have worked, but it can be simplified.

If you provide a property name for the `predicate` argument to `_.find`, it will search that property for the `thisArg` value.

```
function findOb(id) {
    return _.find(myList, 'id', id);
}
```

The only problem I can see with your code is that you use `===` in your comparisons. If you pass `1` as the ID argument instead of `"1"`, it won't match because `===` performs strict type checking.